¿Cómo puedo extraer la línea de debajo de una class con Beautifulsoup?
Me gustaria extraer la linea de debajo de la clase "font_bold"
#!/usr/bin/python
    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests
import jedi
    
website = "https://www.aemet.es/es/eltiempo/prediccion/municipios/algemesi-id46029"
    
    
response = requests.get(website)
    
if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Inicialización")
else:
    pass
    
content = response.text
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
    
soup.find("span", class_="font_bold")
    
soup.find("span", class_="font_bold").string

Salida --> 'Capital:'
Este es el código HTML
<span class="font_bold">Capital:</span>
  Algemesí (altitud: 17 m)

Esta línea "Algemesí (altitud: 17 m)" es la quiero EXTRAER .... Gracias...

Por favor, revisa la edición que previamente se ha hecho a tu pregunta. Si lo haces, notarás cómo darle formato al código para que sea legible.

Por otra parte, muy probablemente esta respuesta responda a tu pregunta.

Efectivamente en la respuesta enlazada por padaleiana se muestra como puedes hacerlo: print(soup.find("span", class_="font_bold").next_sibling). Creo que se puede cerrar como duplicada, pero si tienes algún problema solo comenta, saludos y ¡bienvenido a [es.so]!.
